# Accessing route inside a controller index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently using ASP.Net Core MVC project, so I'm in my view route as:

```
https://localhost:4400/advertisers
```

That view's my index and I have advertisers controller with get and post method:

Get controller:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var advertiserList = await _advertisersService.GetActiveAsync();
        return View(advertiserList);
    }
```

So, in my index view I have a a button "Create Advertiser" as:

```
   <a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Advertisers"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-primary"><i class="bx bx-plus me-1"></i> Add Advertiser</button></a>
```

The method on advertisers controller looks as:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But when I click the button it Chrome throws

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
> address: https://localhost:4400/advertisers/create HTTP ERROR 404

the route it is trying to access is:

```
https://localhost:4400/advertisers/create
```

Thanks in advance

**Startup.cs**

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

    services
        .AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


 [UsedImplicitly]
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider,
        ApplicationDbContext db
    )
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        db.Database.Migrate();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            options =>
            {
                foreach (var groupName in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions.Select(x => x.GroupName))
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{groupName}/swagger.json", $"{groupName}");
            }
        );
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(
            endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the `app.MapControllerRoute()` definition, please?

Comment: I have it as :   app.UseEndpoints(
            endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            }
        );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the following code to the `program.cs`, just for test. This is default conventional routing code and it's working for me, at least;

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); });

app.Run();
```

Comment: I have something like that on y `Startup.cs` (published on the question), and it's almost the same that you have on the program.cs

Comment: @Jesus: Then try to remove `options.LowercaseUrls = true`. Perhaps this is the reason.

Comment: Omg, that was the problem, thanks sir!